# preg_match php to match javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-match, match

i have this function in php :

```
$html_price = "text text 12 eur or $ 22,01 text text";
preg_match_all('/(?<=|^)(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?)(?:\ |)(?:\$|usd|eur)+(?=|$)|(?:\$|usd|eur)(?:| )(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?)/', strtolower($html_price), $price_array1);
print_r($price_array1);
```

Now i want use in javascript the same regex but i have an error:
SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

my javascript :

```
maxime_string = "((?<=|^)(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?)(?:\ |)(?:\$|usd|eur|euro|euros|firm|obro|€|£|gbp|dollar|aud|cdn|sgd|â‚¬)+(?=|$)|(?:\$|usd|eur|euro|euros|firm|obro|€|£|gbp|dollar|aud|cdn|sgd|â‚¬)(?:| )(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?))";
maxime_regex = new RegExp(maxime_string);
var text = "text text 12 eur or $ 22,01 text text";          
var result = text.match(maxime_regex);
var max = result.length;
alert(result.length);
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) 
{ 
document.write(result[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: there's no lookbehind `?<=` in javascript regular expressions

Comment: @bokonic: You should make that an answer. That and the fact that the OP didn't escape the backslashes correctly.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript does not support lookbehind - that's probably where you got your error from. Some things:

- `(?<=|^)` makes no sense. It's a lookbehind demanding either nothing or string begin to come before this - it's always true. And if you want to match the string start, use a single `^`.
- `(?:.[0-9]*)?` - I guess you wanted to escape the dot so it matches literally
- `(?:\ |)`: You do not need to escape blanks. And instead of an alternative "nothing", you should just make the blank optional: " `?`".
- `(?=|$)` makes as much sense as the first group.
- `â‚¬` is a broken unicode character?

Also, you should consider using a regex literal instead of the `RegExp` constructor with a string literal - it eats one level of backslash escaping. And it seems you're missing the *global* flag, so that you get back all matches. Try this:

```
var maxime_regex = /((?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?) ?(?:\$|usd|eur|euro|euros|firm|obro|€|£|gbp|dollar|aud|cdn|sgd|â‚¬)+|(?:\$|usd|eur|euro|euros|firm|obro|€|£|gbp|dollar|aud|cdn|sgd|â‚¬) ?(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?))/g
```

<sub>This post does not include any effort to understand, optimize or shorten that regex monster</sub>

Comment: you wouldn't need to pass a literal to the `RegExp` constructor; it's already a RegExp object

Comment: @bokonic: That's what I meant of course. Edited to clarify :-)

Comment: @user2411447: And that problem is?

Comment: if i want to find 22,3 $ the script return 3 $ , i want "22,3 $", in php with preg_match it's working it's a problem with the coma i think

Comment: `"… 22,3 $ …".match(maxime_regex)` *does* return `Array ["22,3 $"]` for me? Please provide explicit input and expected output.

Comment: with me return only 3 $
var maxime_regex = /((?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?) ?(?:\$|usd|eur|euro|euros|firm|obro|€|£|gbp|dollar|aud|cdn|sgd|â‚¬)+|(?:\$|usd|eur|euro|euros|firm|obro|€|£|gbp|dollar|aud|cdn|sgd|â‚¬) ?(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,| ?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)?|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.?[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9] ​*)?))/g
var text = "19,2 $";          
result = "… 22,3 $ …".match(maxime_regex);